# Forzar tabla overflow-x

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy intentando montar una tabla para ver una serie de datos y resulta que como tiene demasiadas columnas, esta es más ancha que mi pantalla y se sale, a continuación muestro en pantalla el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según he leído, para solucionar esto debo emplear en mi `css` el atributo `overflow-x:scroll`. Pero cómo se ve en la imagen, esto lo consigo a rasgos generales, pero no para la tabla, que es donde yo quiero forzar.

Este es mi código html. Los datos los paso por javascript.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr id="cols_table"></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id=body_table>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y mi css he probado forzando un tamaño (cosa que no quiero)

.table{
    height: auto;
    width: 600px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

y también, dejando que se adapte al `div`, pero ninguna va.

```
.table{
    height: auto;
    width: 90%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

También he probado a forzar que la tabla entre en mi `div` pero se solapa todo...

```
.table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ¿Como hago para que mi tabla no exceda el tamaño de mi pantalla y se ponga la barra de scroll?

Answer (score 0):

La naturaleza de una tabla en HTML es de tipo:

- `inline-table` <sup>1</sup>

Entonces lo que podemos hacer es lo siguiente:

- Alteramos dicho comportamiento por *default* indicándole que ahora será un elemento `block` eso provocará que la tabla abarque toda una fila
- Designamos un ancho predefinido a este elemento por ejemplo `300px`
- Hasta este punto la tabla seguirá mostrando todos sus elementos, sin embargo aquí es donde hacemos uso de `overflow` con el valor de `auto`<sup>2</sup>
- Lo anterior debido a que necesitamos *ocultar* contenido que sobra entonces se dibujará una barra de desplazamiento horizontal

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Demo</title>
      <style>
        body{
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
        }
       .tabla-informe {
          display: block;
          overflow: auto;
          width: 300px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
      <table class="tabla-informe">
      <tr>
        <th>Uno</th>
        <th>Dos</th>
        <th>Tres</th>
        <th>Cuatro</th>
        <th>Cinco</th>
        <th>Seis</th>
        <th>Siete</th>
        <th>Ocho</th>
        <th>Nueve</th>
        <th>Diez</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**REFERENCIAS**

- [display legacy](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/display)
- [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Parece que estas usando bootstrap, votaría por usar esta manera de hacer que se adapte tu tabla. 
Con la clase `table-responsive`.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr id="cols_table"></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id=body_table>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```